# How to detect categorical data masquerading as continuous?

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, continuous-data

Are there any known statistical methods or laws that can be applied towards the detection of categorical data *masquerading* as continuous?

Categorical data can masquerade (or be "obfuscated" in computer parlance) as continuous by a simple replacement scheme such as:

- Original data (categorical): `A, B, B, B, A, C`
- Replacement scheme (mapping): `A -> 1.234, B -> -3.1416, C -> 0.0`
- Masquerading as continuous it becomes: `1.234, -3.1416, -3.1416, -3.1416, 1.234, 0.0`

Comment: Data are not inherently categorical or continuous: these characteristics are *modeling choices.*

Comment: I'm not convinced that @whuber 's comment is for what the question is asking.  For example, consider datasets claimed to be "measurements" with several decimal places that are in fact ratios of counts divided by the sample size.  For example, this seems to happen when relative frequencies are treated as "measurements" and probability distributions are fit with nonlinear regression routines.  A specific example is my answer to the following:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88192/fitting-and-plotting-weibull-distribution.

Comment: @JimB I agree--but the difficulty is that the question as currently phrased is too ambiguous to determine what it's really trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

@whuber makes the correct explanation for this question. The data are categorical, discrete or continuous depending on your construction of the probability space, i.e. they are a modelling choice. For example, all colours visible to the human eye have an order of frequency in the visible electromagnetic spectrum, but you can both consider "blue, green, purple" or their respective frequencies as your data, depending on your problem.

However, if you want a practical solution, I would try (and did before) plotting a frequency table or a histogram to see if there are numerical values in between them. If not, i.e. I would see same values counted various times and conclude that they are in fact categorical variables. I can see where you are coming from, in my case this was a numerical assignment (when was a measurement recorded if I recall correctly).